# Filter queryset by containing a string

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I need to filter all `Alert` objects whose substring is in the given text.

```
class Alert(..):
    substring = CharField...

class Article(...):
    text = ...
```

I was trying `__in` but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
alerts = alerts.filter(Q(substring__isnull=True) | Q(substring='') | Q(substring__in=article.text))
```

Do you know how to do that? I can't use `contains` since it's reverse.

Comment: What is `article`, an `Article` object?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, it's the Article object that has `text` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to inject the `text` of the `article`, and then filter the objects:

```
from django.db.models import F, Q, TextField, Value

Alert.objects.annotate(
    article_text=Value(article.text, output_field=TextField())
).filter(
    Q(substring=None) |
    Q(substring='') |
    Q(article_text__contains=F('substring'))
)
```

Comment: Wow, great! Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure by this line? `article_text=Value(article.text)` It returns `FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field`

Comment: @Milano: what happens if you add an `ouput_field` hint?